# How many computers can connect to a shared folder at the same time on Windows XP Pro?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, file-sharing

I have an older Windows XP Pro desktop with a couple TB of space that I want to use as a Media Server to my nettops, laptops and desktops around my home and home/office, however I'm worried that because it is not a server OS that it will has issues with so many connections being made.

Does anyone know the limit of computers that can connect to a Windows XP Pro desktop at the same time?

Would I be better off setting up a FreeNAS box? Or my old copy of Server 2003?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the max number of connections for XP Pro is [10](http://forums.devshed.com/windows-help-34/win-xp-sp1-max-number-of-connection-for-a-shared-398793.html).

If you're using the pc as a dedicated "server" you could install a linux option which i believe allows as many as your pc can handle.  I personally use Ubuntu [server](http://www.ubuntu.com/server), but that doesn't have a gui interface.  You could use ubuntu [desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop) or any other linux.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and very helpful response. I've looking into Ubuntu Server and it looks interesting, however I'm pretty much a Windows nerd, program in .net and all of that, so I should for my own sake stick with a MS OS. Windows Server 2003 has been sitting in my CD booklet for too long. Time to give it a go.

Comment: OpenFiler http://www.openfiler.com/ is easy to install and is administered via a web interface.  The only gotcha with the configuration is that you need one deeper subfolder than expected when configuring samba shares.  This took me about 3 days to figure out so follow the configuration guide *exactly* to avoid a headache.